# How do you specify Mermaid configuration within Gitlab Markdown?

Tags: gitlab, markdown, mermaid

In Gitlab, I've been able to render an Entity Relationship Diagram with Mermaid in a Markdown file as specified [here](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#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).

This is the Markdown I used:

````
```mermaid
erDiagram
        CUSTOMER }|..|{ DELIVERY-ADDRESS : has
        CUSTOMER ||--o{ ORDER : places
        CUSTOMER ||--o{ INVOICE : "liable for"
        DELIVERY-ADDRESS ||--o{ ORDER : receives
        INVOICE ||--|{ ORDER : covers
        ORDER ||--|{ ORDER-ITEM : includes
        PRODUCT-CATEGORY ||--|{ PRODUCT : contains
        PRODUCT ||--o{ ORDER-ITEM : "ordered in"
                    
```
````

The mermaid interactive editor provides an example of configuration:

```
{
  "theme": "default"
}
```

But I don't know where to locate that configuration information. I've tried putting it in the same directory, in a file called `config.json` or `mermaid-config.json`, but neither of those have worked. I also tried including it in the Markdown which defined the diagram, which only caused it to render incorrectly. Is there a way to specify the theme or other CSS elements for Gitlab?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just tried it out and it worked

````
 ```mermaid 
 %%{init: { 'theme':'dark', 'sequence': {'useMaxWidth':false} } }%%
 sequenceDiagram 
   alice ->> mark: Sent a flower
 ```
````

Comment: Works in GitLab v13.11.4 with built-in Mermaid v8.9.2. Thank you!

Comment: is there any option to switch between dark and default theme as per the background coor of github md file. i am adding the raw mermaid code into the code tag in md. but when theme is changed from dark to light in github no lines are visible.

Comment: This works for Quarto documents too!

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** If you are using a recent enough version of GitLab (possibly [13.9.0 from February, 2021](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1390-2021-02-22), which changes the shipped version of Mermaid [from 8.5.2 to 8.9.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/54f3fcf75d91b79c97ff9f43dfbf62e7a2380d39)) you can use [directives](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/directives), as mentioned in the other answers:

````
```mermaid
%%{init: { 'logLevel': 'debug', 'theme': 'dark' } }%%

graph LR
%%{config: { 'fontFamily': 'Menlo', 'fontSize': 18, 'fontWeight': 400} }%%

A-->B
```
````

Note that Mermaid seems to be sensitive to newlines here. If I add a blank line between `graph LR` and the following `%%{config` line I get a syntax error.

**Original answer for older versions of GitLab:**

I don't believe you can, unless you want to self-host and modify the GitLab source code.

The Mermaid.js configuration in GitLab is [largely hard-coded](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/2e51be2512e603e622df7943b1c9d79b642e5150/app/assets/javascripts/behaviors/markdown/render_mermaid.js#L26-50). It looks like it uses the `neutral` theme by default and switches to the `dark` theme if

- the user is using `dark` or `solarizedDark` as their web IDE theme, and
- if the user is on the IDE web page.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately current GitLab uses mermaidjs version 8.5.2 [as per merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/0f66222d1510ab63c32a0fb92fb3e79de108d0fe)

From mermaid 8.6 onward you should be able to use `directives` to set the theme and/or other settings without touching the hard coded css. For example:

```
%%{init: { 'theme': 'forest' } }%%
erDiagram
   ...
```

I'm afraid we have to wait a little longer, until GitLab updates to this version. You can check in the meantime mermaids [doc](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/directives) on the matter. You can includes this already in your markdown, as the `%%` is interpreted as comments and will not show up in the rendering. But when GitLab makes the move, your pages should immediately update.